# Geometric Interpretation of the Exterior Derivative of a 1-form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms, geometric-interpretation, exterior-derivative

I was reading this [link](https://www.mathphysicsbook.com/mathematics/manifolds/derivatives-on-manifolds/the-exterior-derivative-of-a-1-form/) where says that the geometric interpretation of the exterior derivative of a 1-form $\varphi$ is **“the sum of $\varphi$ on the boundary of the surface defined by its arguments”** and I have some doubts about that sentence.

1. $d\varphi$ is antisymmetric so by definition it must vanish over linearly dependent vector fields. So the part of the bolded sentence where says *“... the surface defined by its arguments”* makes sense: is the infinitesimal surface generated by two linearly independent vector fields. Is this reasoning correct?
2. What is exactly the boundary of an infinitesimal surface?
3. And the most important one: what is the meaning of *“the sum of $\varphi$ on the boundary... ”*? $\varphi$ is a different linear 1-form at each point of the boundary, but those 1-forms live in different vector spaces so, how are you suposed to sum them?

**Any other geometric interpretation for the exterior derivative of a 1-form will be welcome.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Imho the best geometric interpretation of forms and their derivatives is in the book *Gravitation* by Misner, Thorne and Wheeler. I would not get a headache from every sentence someone as put into the internet and in quotation marks.

Comment: I have the book you are talking about. Which page?

Comment: Impatient ? I don't have the book here but remember well that they deal with that subject throughout the book in multiple pedagogical chapters and boxes with lots of pictures.

Comment: Maybe part V of "Visual Differential Geometry and Forms" by Tristan Needham would be somewhat helpful? I haven't read all of it yet though so I'm not sure.